# Check for BST using Level Order Traversal

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

So I have been trying out questions from Hackerrank and there has been a question on checking whether a tree is BST or not. I have been using the level order traversal for this check. if node.left.value> node.value and node.right.value<node.value the Tree must not be a BST.

Apart from the condition where I haven't checked for a single root node, all the other test cases fail. Where have I been going wrong?

```
def checkBST(root):
    
    # if root.left and root.right is None:
    #     return True
    if not root:
            return
    flag=0
    q=[root]
    while len(q)>0:
        temp=q.pop(0)
        if temp.left is not None:
            if temp.left.data> temp.data:
                flag=1
                break
            else:
                q.append(temp.left)
        if temp.right is not None:
            if temp.right.data<temp.data:
                flag=1
                break
            else:
                q.append(temp.right)
            
    if flag==1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to test that a direct child is in the correct relation to its parent. There are invalid BSTs for which all those comparison-tests pass. You need to ensure that in the *whole* left subtree of a node there is no node with a greater value than that node's value.

So a level order traversal is not really the right tool to do this. It will work better with an in-order traversal, since a BST will have an non-decreasing in-order traversal.